# onKeyDown doesn't work if webView

Tags: java, android, webview

If I add a webview on the layout, the override of onKeyDown doesn't fires, but I get this log in the console.

```
D/WebViewCallback: shouldOverrideKeyEvent
D/WebViewCallback: onUnhandledKeyEvent
```

If I remove the webview, all works fine.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d("MainVX","Button Click");
}
```

I also tried to use **shouldOverrideKeyEvent** but says that it's deprecated.